# Can you please help me modify this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The following code works great in terms of enforcing validation rules.

```
function validate() {

    if (document.getElementById("<%=txtName.ClientID%>").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter name");
        document.getElementById("<%=txtName.ClientID%>").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("<%=txtCity.ClientID %>").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter city");
        document.getElementById("<%=txtCity.ClientID %>").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("<%=txtState.ClientID%>").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter state");
        document.getElementById("<%=txtState.ClientID%>").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("<%=txtZip.ClientID%>").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter zip");
        document.getElementById("<%=txtZip.ClientID%>").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (checkradio() == false) {
        alert("Please enter contacts");
        document.getElementById("<%=txtContacts.ClientID%>").focus();
        return false;
    }
     return true;
}
```

My issue is that the form is broken into 2 sections, section 1 and section 2.

Second 1 contains required form fields and section 2 contains option field.

The rule is that you cannot select from both sections at same time. You can either select from section 1 OR section 2.

Section 1 has above form fields that are required and section 2 ahas form fields on the same form that are optional.

If I select from section 1, everything is fine.

If I selection from section 2, since they are on the same form, the validation rules kick in.

Is there a way to condition the form to say, if form fields from section 2 are NOT blank, then no validation rules are in effect?

Better yet, in classic asp, you can have multiple forms in one file.

Is that possible in asp.net?

I think this will eliminate the validation from kicking in when selecting from optional fields.

Sorry for long thread.

Comment: Kenny, if my answer below helped, please mark it as such; otherwise please let us know what else you need help with.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I am trying to figure out how to use multiple forms in asp.net. Once I can figure that out, then I will check out your proposed solution. I will post back as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is possible to have multiple forms in ASP.NET, just add multiple forms in your markup.
2. In your validate function, first check if any of the controls of form2 are set, and then return true; otherwise proceed with other checks.

   ```
   function validate() {

   if(... check if any controls of form 2 are set ...) return true;

   // Otherwise proceed with checks for form 1

   if (document.getElementById("<%=txtName.ClientID%>").value == "") {
       alert("Please enter name");
       document.getElementById("<%=txtName.ClientID%>").focus();
       return false;
   }

   ....
   ```

Comment: please fix `function validate() {`. (this msg will self-destruct when you/someone make the edit)

Comment: i was able to fix it by using just one form and the following: if txtfield1FromSection2 !="" && txtfield2FromSection2 {

return true; otherwise they are empty, validate form fields in section one. It works fine but I still like Andrew's logic even though I could not get it all together.